# Tensorflow - GPU dedicated vs shared memory

Tags: python, memory, tensorflow, gpu

Does Tensorflow use only dedicated GPU memory or can it also use shared memory?

Also I ran this:

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

device_lib.list_local_devices()

> [name: "/device:CPU:0"
>    device_type: "CPU"
>    memory_limit: 268435456
>
> name: "/device:GPU:0"
>    device_type: "GPU"
>    memory_limit: 112128819

What are these "memory limits" 268,435,456 and 112,128,819 ?

Here is what I am talking about - when I ran TF on Win10, shared memory is always zero and yet I get ResourceExhaustedError if my batch size is too large. It just seems the shared memory is never used.

[image: TF not using shared memory]

Comment: If uses both dedicated GPU memory and shared memory (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4be5afc8b656cf6b540b547a1faafd2a0a82f5f2/tensorflow/core/kernels/concat_lib_gpu_impl.cu.cc#L72). These values are described here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5a5a25ea3ebef623e07fb9a46419a9df377a37a5/tensorflow/core/framework/device_attributes.proto#L22

Comment: I can only observe the usage of dedicated memory (in nvidia-smi and Windows Task Manager) but I cannot see if it's using shared at all. How can I confirm that?

Comment: Do you mean this [shared memory](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/)? This shared memory ***is*** used by CUDA kernels, like a c malloc used memory on the host side.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Tensorflow only uses the dedicated GPU memory as described below. At that time, memory_limit = max dedicated memory - current dedicated memory usage (observed in the Win10 task manager)

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Output:

```
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 2196032718
```

To verify this , I tried to use for a single task (Tensorflow 2 benchmark from https://github.com/aime-team/tf2-benchmarks), it gives "Resource exhausted" error as below on a GTX1060 3GB with Tensorflow 2.3.0.

```
2021-01-20 01:50:53.738987: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.7085GHz coreCount: 9 deviceMemorySize: 3.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s

Limit:                      2196032718
InUse:                      1997814016
MaxInUse:                   2155556352
NumAllocs:                        1943
MaxAllocSize:                551863552
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2021-01-20 01:51:21.393175: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops.cc:539 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,256,56,56] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I have tried to do the same with multiple small tasks. It tries to use the shared GPU memory for multiple tasks with different Juypter kernels, but the newer task ultimately fails.

For an example with two similar Xception models :

Task 1: runs without an error

Task 2: fails with below error

```
UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node xception/block1_conv1/Conv2D (defined at <ipython-input-25-0c5fe80db9f1>:3) ]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_5303]

Function call stack:
predict_function
```

GPU Memory usage at the failure (note the usage of shared memory at the start of the Task 2)

[image: GPU Memory usage at the failure]

Comment: I am not sure if this is an attempt to answer the question or not, in any case this place is for answers to the question, not comments or unrelated discussion.