# How does TensorFlow use both shared and dedicated GPU memory on the GPU on Windows 10?

Tags: tensorflow, memory-management, windows-10

When running a TensorFlow job I sometimes get a non-fatal error that says GPU memory exceeded, and then I see the "Shared memory GPU usage" go up on the Performance Monitor on Windows 10.

How does TensorFlow achieve this?  I have looked at CUDA documentation and not found a reference to the Dedicated and Shared concepts used in the Performance Monitor.  There is a Shared Memory concept in CUDA but I think it is something on the device, not the RAM I see in the Performance Monitor, which is allocated by the BIOS from CPU RAM.

Note: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492079/tensorflow-gpu-dedicated-vs-shared-memory) was asked but not answered by another poster.

Answer (score 2):

Shared memory in windows 10 does **not** refer to the same concept as [cuda shared memory](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/) (or [local memory](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/local.html) in opencl), [it refers to host accessible/allocated memory from the GPU](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/251763-microsoft-shares-new-details-gpu-monitoring-capabilities-windows-10-fall-creators-update).   For integrated graphics processing host and device memory is usually the same as shared thanks to both the cpu and gpu being located on the same die and being able to access the same ram.  For dedicated graphics with their own memory, this is separate memory allocated on the host side for use by the GPU.

Shared memory for compute APIs such as through GLSL compute shaders, or Nvidia CUDA kernels refer to a programmer managed cache layer (some times refereed to as ["scratch pad memory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratchpad_memory)) which on Nvidia devices, exists per SM, and can only be accessed by a single SM and is usually between 32kB to 96kB per SM. Its purpose is to speed up memory access to data which is used often.

**If you see and increase shared memory used in Tensorflow, you have a dedicated graphics card, and you are experiencing "GPU memory exceeded" it most likely means you are using too much memory on the GPU itself, so it is trying to allocate memory from elsewhere (IE from system RAM).**  This potentially can make your program much slower as the bandwidth and latency will be much worse on non device memory for a dedicated graphics card.

Comment: The question was not, is this a good or bad thing, but how does TensorFlow do it? I don't see calls in the CUDA library that look like they do that.  In Windows 10 Task manager, if you switch to Performance GPU view, it has 3 items "Dedicated GPU Memory", which is what is on the GPU chip, "Shared GPU Memory", which is what is allocated from RAM to the GPU, and "GPU Memory", which is the sum of the two.

Comment: @LarsEricson my answer had nothing to do with "good or bad" about anything, and your question seemed to stem from a lack of understanding of what shared memory refers to in different contexts.   It appeared that you were asking "How does TensorFlow achieve this"  in reference to how does Tensorflow end up using shared memory.  I answered that question.  It does so by allocating too much memory, and having it spill over host side.   Shared memory you see is often driver allocated space, and not managed by the programmer.   Tensorflow does not manually allocate this memory.

Comment: I ran a TensorFlow program for neural network training and it said "GPU reports out of memory but this is not fatal" and then proceeded to allocate additional memory in the "Shared GPU Memory" bucket shown by Windows will maxing out the "Dedicated GPU Memory" bucket.  I also know that in the BIOS you can map some RAM to the GPU on a permanent basis.  I also know that the cudaMalloc call doesn't do this sort of thing.  I just want to know exactly what TF does in this case.  I don't care if it is efficient or not, I just care what call is being made.

Comment: @LarsEricson Like I said, I don't think TF does this, It is just the driver doing this automatically.

Comment: Here is the exact message: "Allocator (GPU_1_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.55GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available." quoted in 2nd answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725179/tensorflow-memory-use-while-running-on-gpu-why-does-it-look-like-not-all-memory?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out by accident.  The "Shared GPU Memory" reported by Windows 10 Task Manager Performance tab does get used, if there are multiple processes hitting the GPU simultaneously.  I discovered this by writing a Python programming that used multiprocessing to queue up multiple GPU tasks, and I saw the "Shared GPU memory" start filling up.  This is the only way I've seen it happen.

So it is only for queueing tasks.  Each individual task is still limited to the onboard DRAM minus whatever is permanently allocated to actual graphics processing, which seems to be around 1GB.