# Uneven Multiple GPUs usage using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, parallel-processing, gpu, multi-gpu

I am training a model using tensorflow, somehow only the first two GPU were used heavily, occupying 10000 MiB and 9290 MiB, respectively.

I have eight GPUs, the six other GPUs were used but only 300 MB each. Does anyone know why the GPU usage is not evenly distributed across all GPUs?

I use the following code:

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = create_unet_model()
    model.compile(...)
    model.fit(...)
```

I looked it up, but no one could suggest any possible reason.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? You can post the answer if so. If not, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65655444/4548767) or [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu_performance_analysis) might help? Also your profile pic/name inspired me to rewatch that show :)